# Rails Use JQuery to Show Records in View Based on onClick Event

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using `ruby 2.5.1` and `rails 5.0`

I've read a few threads that are close to what I want but haven't found one that fits close enough for me to apply it to what I need.

I have a view that displays weight lifting exercises recorded by date. Showing ALL records is not useful as it lists too many too fast. Currently, in my controller I have this to get all records for last week - seven (7) days:

```
@weights = Fitness::Weight.where(admin_user_id: session[:user_id])
                          .where(created_at: 7.days.ago.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now.end_of_day)
                          .order(workout_date: :desc)
```

In my view I do the usual:

```
<% @weights.each do |w| %>
...
```

In the controller, I would like to create three instance objects: one each for the current date, the last 3-days and the last 7-days.  I know how to do this.  In my view, I want to add three buttons - one for each instance var.  When a button is clicked, the page will not submit, but JQuery will hide all the records currently showing and then only show those for the instance var tied to the button clicked.

I've done this loads of times with PHP and JQuery.  I know I can create the three instance objects in the controller and then in my view, using `<div>`s, I can use JQuery to show/hide the `<div>` associated to the button clicked.  I thought maybe there is a more railsy way to do this.  I read a thread once about using partials for each set of records to show and somehow using JQuery to trigger which partial gets loaded in my view.  But, (sigh), I cannot find that thread again.

I'm good at coding up to when a button is clicked. From there, in rails, I'm not sure how to make it load the instance object/var and/or partial.  I'm hoping someone might point me in the right direction: to a tutorial, thread or with some simple hints on how to do this.

Or, maybe there is a better, more railsy, way

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a foundation tabs.

https://get.foundation/sites/docs/tabs.html

There is also great foundation gem for rails

https://github.com/foundation/foundation-rails